# how do i join third table values into main join?

Tags: mysql, sql

in query here i have https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/32Kc3QisUEwmSM8EmULpgd/1

```
SELECT p.prank, d.dare 
FROM dares d
INNER JOIN pranks p ON p.id = d.prank_id
WHERE d.condo_id = 1;
```

i have one `condo` with id 1 and it have unique connection to `dares` that has connection to pranks and unique connection to `condos_pranks`

and i wanna have all unique pranks from both tables and i used this query above to get relation of

`dares to pranks` and expected result was `L,M,N - Yes,No,Maybe` and it is correct but i also wanna have those in `condos_pranks` which ids are `1,4,5,6 = L,O,P,Q`

so i tried to join the table with left join because it might not have `condos_pranks` row

```
SELECT p.prank, d.dare 
FROM dares d
INNER JOIN pranks p ON p.id = d.prank_id
LEFT JOIN condos_pranks pd ON pd.condo_id = d.condo_id AND pd.prank_id = p.id
WHERE d.condo_id = 1;
```

but result is same as first and what i want is

| prank | dare |
| --- | --- |
| L | Yes |
| M | No |
| N | Maybe |
| O | No |
| P | No |
| Q | No |

with default being `No = 2` if prank_id of `condos_pranks` is not in `dares`

how to connect it?

Comment: Is this a table structure you were given? Or one you are creating? Seems to be some circular joins going on here that could be removed for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an exercise in identifying extraneous information more than anything. You are unable to join something to a table that has no key, however if you know your default then you may use something like coalesce to identify the records where there was no data to join `NULL` and replace them with your default.

I mentioned in a comment above that this table schema makes little sense. You have keys all over the place that doing have all sorts of circular references. If this is your derived schema, consider stopping here and revisiting the relationships. If it is not and it is something educational, which I suspect it is, disregard and recognize the logical flaws in what you are working in. Perhaps consider taking the data provided and creating a new table schema that is more normalized and uses other tables to handle the many to many and one to many relationships.

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u1x4VcEaaE5qgppcx6WhKB/0)

```
SELECT 
   pranks.prank,
   COALESCE(dares.dare, 'No')
FROM pranks LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dares ON pranks.id = dares.prank_id
ORDER BY pranks.prank ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

clearlyclueless gave correct explanations
To achieve the result, the following SELECT can also be used:

```
SELECT 
    pranks.prank,
    case 
    when dare is null then 'No'
    else dare
    end
FROM pranks LEFT  OUTER JOIN 
    dares ON pranks.id = dares.prank_id
```